# Cannot add an item to the Collection property. Please hеlр me, please

Tags: c#, list, asynchronous, concurrency, synchronization

I am trying to add an item to the SynchronizedCollection but it works only if I add it directly into the field.

```
        _s = new SynchronizedCollection<int>();
        _s.Add(01010);
        S.Add(123);

    private SynchronizedCollection<int>  _s;
    public SynchronizedCollection<int> S
    {
        get
        {

            lock (_s.SyncRoot)
            {
                return new SynchronizedCollection<int>(_s.SyncRoot, _s);
            }
        }

        private set
        {
            _s= value;
        }
    }
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Your `get` return each time new instance of the collection, you should return `_s`... So you are adding element to the new collection which you then actually throw away...:)

Comment: Your `set` is private, so you haven't provided access to to add an item outside of the class.

Comment: You might consider using one of the  [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) collections instead, possibly the [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8) class.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how you're trying to add an item, and how you're verifying that it doesn't get added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it works only if I add it directly into the field

Because you didn't assign newly created `SynchronizedCollection` to `_s`. Every time you call `S` getter the new collection is created, all elements are [copied](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.servicemodel/system/servicemodel/SynchronizedCollection.cs,39), and the element is added to it. `_s` actually stays untouched.

```
lock (_s.SyncRoot)
{
    _s = new SynchronizedCollection<int>(_s.SyncRoot, _s);
    return _s;
}
```

Although I don't think it is needed to create new collection each time, `SynchronizedCollection` itself is thread-safe so you could just return `_s` but don't know actual scenario why are you doing that.

Comment: It answer actually. The question is why item has not been added to collection using getter but only field.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Made a slight edit so I can remove the down vote~!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to expose a public `AddItem` method that takes an `int` and adds it to your private field:

```
public void AddItem(int item)
{
    _s.Add(item);
}
```

Obviously you could also return the private field `_s` in the `get` method instead of a copy of it, and then clients could call `Add` directly on the private field through that reference, but then there's not much point in it being private. :)